# C# multithreading and Serial port to slow

Tags: c#, multithreading, serial-communication

I am a beginner at C# and would like some advice on how to solve the following problem:

My main code include 2 thread, first thread is for sending data and the second one is for reading data from serial communications. When I press the start button, the communication begin to work in two while loop.

```
    private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         beri_podatke = true;

        Thread read_thr = new Thread(read);
        read_thr.Start();
     }
```

First thread (sending data):

```
    private void read()
    {
            while (read_data_on)
        {
            if (sinh == 1 )
              {

                serialPort1.Write(new byte[] { 0x55, 0x40, 0x05 }, 0, 3);
                serialPort1.Write(new byte[] { 0x55, 0x1c }, 0, 2);
                sinh = 2;
            }
             if (sinh == 3 )
            {
                serialPort1.Write(new byte[] { 0x55, 0x40, 0x65 }, 0, 3);
                serialPort1.Write(new byte[] { 0x55, 0x1c }, 0, 2);
                sinh = 4;
            }
         }
```

Second thread (receiving data):

```
    private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
      while (read_data_on)
        {
            if (sinh == 2 )
           {
               byte[] input1 = new byte[3];
               int st_bajtov1 = serialPort1.Read(input1, 0, 3);

                   vrednost1 = (input1[2] << 16) | (input1[1] << 8) | (input1[0]);
                   sinh = 3;                    
            }

           if (sinh == 4 )
           {
               byte[] input2 = new byte[3];
               int st_bajtov2 = serialPort1.Read(input2, 0, 3);

                 vrednost2 = (input2[2] << 16) | (input2[1] << 8) | (input2[0]);
                 sinh = 1;
           }
       }
   }
```

The problem is that the communication speed between the device and pc is to slow. I am using 115200 baud rate and I get maximum send data frequency 300 Hz - 350 Hz.

[send_receive_data_time.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpUbS.png)

I want twice the speed or even more, because I am reading register of measuring device and I need much more samples for my master degree. I disable all other code as is calculating, char, label,.. and there is no impact on sending speed. Program is running on core i9 PC. What could be wrong or is there a solution?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/how-to-synchronize-concurrent-operations-with-a-barrier

Answer (score -1):

"The ruling constraint" is very obviously the hardware.